# How to show modal when I click specific banner in opencart

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, opencart, banner

I want to show my modal when I click a banner. I am using openCart
Here's my code:

JQUERY

```
$('img[alt="banner-interview"]').click(function() {
    $('#modal-watch').modal('show'); 
});
```

MODAL

```
<div class="md-modal md-effect-8" id="modal-watch">
 <div class="md-content"> 
  <h3 style="background-color:orange; font-size: 20px;">Title Here</h3>
    <div>
            <iframe width="850" height="500" scrolling="no"
                        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxx">
            </iframe>
        <button class="md-close"  style="background-color:orange;">Close me!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Do you want to show your clicked image in the modal?

Comment: No, I want to show my modal when I clicked a specific banner. By the way, my banner name is "banner-interview".

Comment: My jquery is working. I tried to output an alert when I click that banner. Now, I don't know ho to show my modal when I click my banner

Answer (score 0):

you can use a Lightbox for Bootstrap 3, this facility display image or any url on lightbox modal windows like:

```
<a href="your uls of image" data-toggle="lightbox">Launch modal</a>
```

http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/

Comment: hi. banner cannot be <a href> in open cart :(

Comment: You can use javascript instead: $('#mylink').ekkoLightbox(options);